# Comparing retention rates with differing sample sizes

Tags: statistical-significance, sample-size, weighted-mean, percentage

I'm looking to compare the retention rate of people who attended an event and those who did not. The list of those who did not (70) is significantly larger than those who have (28).

Here is an example of the data I'm looking to compare: 
In April 7 people left - of those 3 attended the event and 4 did not. 
I've calculated the retention rate of attended as (28-3)/28 = 89.29%
I've calculated the retention rate of non-attendees as (70-4)/70 = 94.29%

Due to the sample size, I don't think it's a proper comparison but I need a way to compare them.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are comparing categorical variables (stayed or left) on two groups, you can use a Chi-square test of independence, which does not require equal sample sizes.
http://stattrek.com/chi-square-test/independence.aspx?tutorial=ap

Answer (score 0):

I would comment but it seems I need reputation to do so.

What you are looking for is a test for equal proportions. Sample sizes need not be equal.

This webpage will be of assistance:

https://web.archive.org/web/20150216093850/https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/268

Edit: I am assuming you know how to use a test statistic once you have obtained it. Let me know if this is not the case.

Comment: I'm afraid im not quite understanding how this would work given the example.

Comment: Ok. I need some idea of your background in statistics. Is this homework for an introductory class, or have you taken/are taking one?